# Permissions keep changing on Desktop

Tags: icloud, high-sierra, permission, apache

I am running a Apache2 on my MBP on macOS 10.13.6. I setup everything well, and it works when going to `localhost/~user`. In my `~/Sites` folder, I have a symbolic link to a folder on my Desktop with my website files in it. I can navigate to the website with `localhost/~user/mysite` only sometimes. If I get a 403 error, it is fixed with running `chmod a+x ~/Desktop`. This fixes it until about the next reload, but almost every time I make a change and try to reload the site, I have to run the `chmod` command. I use Brackets for my web editing, and I have iCloud Drive syncing enabled for the Desktop folder. I think that it is either the iCloud Drive resetting permissions for the folder or Brackets doing something weird. Has anyone had a similar problem and fixed it? This is really annoying and it's slowing down my development.

EDIT: My httpd.conf file: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/vJaCEqdR)

EDIT: It seems my question was unclear, but what I was asking is why the permissions keep changing on my ~/Dekstop folder. I do `chmod a+x ~/Desktop` and it fixes my apache 403 errors, but after about a minute this changes and I have to run the chmod command again. I was thinking it might be iCloud Drive sync changing something, or Brackets messing up permissions.

Comment: A symlink on your desktop isn't going to change the permissions for a folder somewhere else.  What does your `httpd.conf` file look like? (Most likely off topic since it will be related to Apache and not Apple, but let's take a look).

Comment: @Allan I added a pastebin to the post. (https://pastebin.com/vJaCEqdR)

Comment: @Minebomber I am confused on what the question is here exactly? Can you edit to clarify what you exactly are asking? Do you want to know about permissions or how to get apache to work with desktop folder?

Comment: What does `ls -ld ~/Desktop` show when it is broken

Comment: did you create your symlink from the document root to the desktop:  `ln -s /Users/mark/Sites /Users/mark/Desktop/Sites`

Comment: @Allan I did ln -s /Users/mark/Desktop/MySite /Users/mark/Sites/MySite

Comment: That's the issue, you've done it backward.  It's `ln -s /path/to/source path/to/target` where the "target" is the linkfile.

Comment: @Allan I might have typed that wrong. The link works as expected on my machine, so I don't believe that is the issue. Also, I only have this issue on my MBP, and I have the same setup as my 10.12 hackintosh.

Comment: Double check.  Because a DocumentRoot directive that points to a symlink *will* work until something changes the permission is the directory.  Also your Desktop permissions are completely incorrect for DocumentRoot...

Comment: @Allan I did ls when it was broken, and I got this: `drwx------@ 17 mark  staff   544B Sep  2 20:02 Desktop/`

Comment: Also, what did you mean about the incorrect permissions for DocumentRoot

Comment: `ls -ld` after the `chmod` command gives: `drwx--x--x@ 17 mark  staff   544B Sep  2 20:02 Desktop/`

Comment: Your permissions should be 775 meaning read/write/execute for owner and group and only read/execute for everyone else.  What you have is read/write/execute for owner and execute *only* for group and other.  The way you have it set, only the *owner* you can actually read documents in the directory and the way you have it linked is Apache looks for a directory in your home folder and finds a symlink on your Desktop.

Comment: I have the same issue. My local website is inside my Documents folder (so it is automatically backed up to the cloud) and it looks like every time iCloud syncs it resets the Documents folder's permission to 700 which results in a 403 Forbidden on my localhost. Manually changing permission on the Documents folder to 755 fixes it, but obviously this isn't ideal. Every folder in the entire path to my localhost has 755 permissions and it only takes this one Documents folder to change permissions for my localhost to stop working. If we can't disable the automatic permissions resetting during iCloud

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Documents folder. I solved it by using ACLs to grant access.

`chmod +a "_www allow list,search" Desktop`

For more information, see [my answer to a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398798/385685).